# Clicking on a headline div shows the details of the div and hide other div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How can I make a page which shows list of headlines on the left sidebar and when I click on a headline it will show the details of the headlines.

[image: here is the demo like gmail. in left it shows the headlines,when I click on a headline I shows the details and the headline get highlighted]

here is the demo like gmail. in left it shows the headlines,when I click on a headline I shows the details and the headline get highlighted

Comment: You are trying to create a panel - take a look at the last example on [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_panels.asp) it might give you a hint on where to start

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

**index.html**

```
<body>
<div class="to-show">
<h1>Toggle</h1>
</div>
<div class="to-click">
<h1>Click Here</h1>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="" src="./index.js"
</body>
```

**index.js**

```
$(".to-click").on("click",()=>
{
$(".to-show").toggle();
})
```

Comment: this is not hiding other divs and also not getting clicked element highlighted

Comment: add `".to-show"` class to all the divs, you want to hide and it will work. for highlighting the element, create a class named "highlight-element" in css. and use `$(".to-click").addClass("highlight-element")`  right above the `$(".to-show").toggle();` line in index.js